# Parse ISO string to date

Tags: python, django

I am trying to parse

> 2020-09-18T16:11:03.4411565+00:00

Code

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.isoparse('2020-09-18T16:11:03.4411565+00:00')
```

I am getting

ValueError: Unused components in ISO string

Also i am using 3.6.9 so i can't use `datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)` What can I do?

Comment: if you can  do it with pandas then pd.to_datetime(['2020-09-18T16:11:03.4411565+00:00'], infer_datetime_format=True) might help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`parser.parse(...)`** function

```
In [1]: from dateutil import parser                                                                                                                                                                                

In [2]: dt_str = '2020-09-18T16:11:03.4411565+00:00'                                                                                                                                                               

In [3]: parser.parse(dt_str)                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 18, 16, 11, 3, 441156, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 1):

iso format accepts 6 digit after '.' (usec). You have 7.

Modify your string to '2020-09-18T16:11:03.441156+00:00'

Comment: This works in my case `2021-05-10T00:00:00-01:30` but this doesn't `2021-05-10T00:00:00+01:30`. Why is that?